# Counts within csv

Tags: c#, arrays, csv, count, split

I am trying to write a program for a school project that will read a csv file containing a name on each line and output each name and the number of times it occurrences in a list box. I would prefer for it not to be pre set for a specific name but i guess that would work also. So far i have this but now I'm stuck.

This is what I have so far:

```
string[] csvArray;
string line;
StreamReader reader;
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

//set filter for dialog control
const string FILTER = "CSV Files|*.csv|All Files|*.*";
openFileDialog.Filter = FILTER;

//if user opens file and clicks ok
if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    //open input file
    reader = File.OpenText(openFileDialog.FileName);

    //while not end of stream
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        //read line from file
        line = reader.ReadLine().ToLower();

        //split values
        csvArray = line.Split(',');
```

Comment: i will have a single name on a line so a new line for each name and comma separated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing your full CSV structure, I would do something like:

```
//outside of loop
var nameCounterDict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

//in loop
//csvName is the name of the current csv token you're parsing
int itemCount = 0;

if(!nameCounterDict.TryGetValue(csvName, out itemCount))
    nameCounterDict.Add(csvName, 0)

nameCounterDict[csvName]++;
```

This populates a  dictionary with each occurrence of a unique name, if the name already exists, it will increment an int count.

After you've parsed the file, you could then loop the dictionary to get each name and the counter for display.